# how objects values are retained when we drain the pool at the end of run loop

Tags: iphone, ios

I know this sounds like a dumb question but I need to ask this. Well I read that autorelease pool is drained after one iteration of run loop after it has handled events. My question is that then how come my apps objects are retained after I clicked on button. So, by definition It should destroy all the objects which I have created (may be I have assigned some values to objects) after I click on button. But that doesnt happen ? right ? I can click my button again and again but I dont lose any object data.
Correct me if I am wrong somewhere.

Comment: you accidentally the whole code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should watch a video or two from https://developer.apple.com/videos/ - Great introductions to memory management and such. And I also strongly recommend you look into ARC as soon as you grasp the basics of retain/release/autorelease.

Answer (score 0):

All that the autorelease pool does is decrement the retain count of objects in the pool when it is drained.  If that results in the retain count becoming zero, the object will be destroyed (dealloc'ed).

However, if an object has been retained more than once, the retain count will be greater than zero so it will not be destroyed (note that objects are created with a retain count of 1.)